# sparkR write.df to coalesce into one file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

In sparkR , I am writing the output into a single file rather than many part files. Could you please advise how to use coalesce in the write.df as shown below:

```
write.df(user_counts, path = '/aaa/bbb/cccc/', source = "csv", mode = "append")
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this document](https://amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg/rdocs/1.2/coalesce.html) SparkR ver 1.2 the following return a new DF with only 1 partition:

```
coalesce(df_name, 1)
```

According to [SparkR ver 2.1 document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html) the following return a new DF with only 1 partition:

```
repartition(x, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its  gives me expected results.

Comment: @Bhaskar - I'm happy that my answer helped you. Can you please accept my answer?